# Вывести все значения циклом

Tags: php

как переделать этот код:

```
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $sql2['count']; $i++) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inv where username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
    $inv = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "

    i[$i] = new Array('".$inv['id']."','".$inv['id_img']."','".$inv['kolovo']."',0,'".$inv['title']."',0,'".$inv['about']."',0,1);

    ";
}
```

Чтоб выводились **ВСЕ** значения , а не только одно?

Вот весь код:

```
<?php
session_start();
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(pokefriends) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<HTML>

<HEAD>

 <TITLE>Инвентарь</TITLE>

 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; Charset=Windows-1251">
<STYLE>
body {

    background: #2685c9;
        COLOR: #fedab3;
        FONT-SIZE: 13px;
        FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma;

}
#divTip {              
              position:absolute;
              padding:1 2 1 2;
              background-color: #2685c9;
              border: solid 1px 2685c9;
              text-align:justify;
              COLOR: #fedab3;
              FONT-SIZE: 11px; 
              FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; z-index:10;
              visibility:hidden;

}

</STYLE>

 <script>

 function defPosition(event) { // координаты мыши

    var x = y = 0;

    if (document.attachEvent != null) {

        x = window.event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);

        y = window.event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);

    } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {

        x = event.clientX + window.scrollX;

        y = event.clientY + window.scrollY;

    } else {

        // Do nothing

    }

    return {x:x, y:y};

 }

 page=0;

 invType=0;

 function tip(event, ID) {

   if (event) {

     document.getElementById('divTip').style.left=defPosition(event).x+15;

     document.getElementById('divTip').style.top=defPosition(event).y+10;

     document.getElementById('divTip').innerHTML=i[ID][15];

     document.getElementById('divTip').style.visibility='visible';

   } else document.getElementById('divTip').style.visibility='hidden';

 }

 function pic(ID,sitID,am,uw,dr) {

   for (s=0;s<document.images.length;s++)

   document.images[s].style.border='1px solid #aecff1';

   document.getElementById("pic"+ID).style.border='1px solid black';

   document.getElementById('formit')['itID'].value=sitID;

   document.getElementById('formit')['amount'].value=am;

   document.getElementById('formit')['but1'].style.display=(uw?'inline':'none');

   document.getElementById('formit')['but2'].style.display=(dr?'inline':'none');

   document.getElementById('formit')['pokes'].style.display=(uw||dr?'block':'none');

   eval("CURpic.src=pic"+ID+".src");

   CURname.innerHTML=document.getElementById('divTip').innerHTML;

 }

 function formatnum(str) {
    str = str + '';

    var retstr = '';

    var now = 0;

    for (j = str.length-1; j>=0; j--) {

        if (now < 3)    {

            now++;

            retstr = str.charAt(j) + retstr;

        } else {

            now = 1;

            retstr = str.charAt(j) + '.' + retstr;

        }

    }

    return retstr;

 }

 function use_item(add) {
    document.getElementById('add').value=add;

    document.getElementById('formit').submit();

 }
<?php 
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM inv WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'"); 
 $sql2 = @mysql_fetch_array($sql);

?>

 itemsamount = <?php echo $sql2['count'];  ?> ;i = new Array( <?php echo $sql2['count'];  ?>);

i[0] = new Array(<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>,1,<?php echo $row['money']; ?>,0,'Кредит',0,'Вес: 0<br>',0,6);
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= $sql2['count']; $i++) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inv where username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$inv = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "

i[$i] = new Array('".$inv['id']."','".$inv['id_img']."','".$inv['kolovo']."',0,'".$inv['title']."',0,'".$inv['about']."',0,1);

";
}

?>

function fillupinv() {
      p=page*40;

      content="";

      prints=1;

      while (prints<=40 && i[p]) {
        if (invType==0 || i[p][8]==invType) {

            picF=i[p][1]+'.gif';

            if (i[p][1]>=74 && i[p][1]<=123) picF='TM'+'.gif';

            if (i[p][1]>=123 && i[p][1]<=130) picF='HM'+'.gif';

            if (i[p][1]==250) picF='cards/'+i[p][7]+'.gif';

            if (i[p][1]==144) picF = i[p][7] ? 'eggs/'+i[p][7]+'.png' : '144.gif';

            i[p][15]= i[p][4] + ' <b><small>x</small>'+formatnum(i[p][2])+'</b>';

            if (i[p][6]) i[p][15]+='<br><span class=itemdescr>'+i[p][6]+'</span>';

            content+="<div class=item><img class='item' ID=\"pic"+p+"\" src=\"/img/item/"+picF+"\" onClick=\"pic("+p+","+i[p][0]+","+i[p][2]+","+i[p][3]+","+i[p][5]+")\" onMouseMove=\"tip(event,"+p+");\" onMouseOut=\"tip(0); \"></div>";

            prints++;

        }

        p++;

      }

      for (k=prints; k<=40; k++) content+="<div class=item><img src='/img/item/blank.gif'></div>";

      document.getElementById('inv').innerHTML=content;

      if (page>0) {document.getElementById('divprev').innerHTML="<a href='javascript:' onclick='page--;fillupinv();'><<</a>";} else {document.getElementById('divprev').innerHTML="<span style='color:#92b1dd'>&lt;&lt;</span>";}

      if (itemsamount>p) {document.getElementById('divnext').innerHTML="<a href='javascript:' onclick='page++;fillupinv();'>>></a>";} else {document.getElementById('divnext').innerHTML="<span style='color:#92b1dd'>&gt;&gt;</span>";}

 }

 </script>

 <STYLE>

    IMG {width:32; height:32; visibility:visible; border:1px solid #aecff1; margin:3px}

    IMG.item{CURSOR:POINTER;}

    BODY {margin:5 5 5 5;}

    div.item {

        background-color:#4c91f9;

        margin:1px;

        float:left;

        width: 40px;

        height: 40px;

    }

 </STYLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY onload="fillupinv()" style="width:600; height:350;">

<H1>Инвентарь</H1>

<div id="divTip"></div>

<TABLE align="left" width="600"><TR><TD width="345" valign=top>

<DIV ID="inv">

</DIV>

<br><TABLE width="335" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;">

  <TD align=left><DIV id="divprev">

  </DIV></TD><TD align=center>

    <small><a href="javascript:history.go(0)">- обновить -</a></small>

  </TD><TD align=right><DIV id="divnext">

  </DIV></TD>

</TABLE>

</TD><TD valign=top>

<DIV id="CURname">&nbsp;</DIV>

<br>

<img ID="CURpic" src="/img/item/blank.gif" width="32" height="32" border="0" style="CURSOR:DEFAULT"><br>
<form action="game.php?fun=use_item&map=1" method="post" id="formit">
  <input name="amount" type="text" value="" SIZE=10><BR>
  <input name="but0" type="button" value="Выкинуть" onclick="if (confirm('Вы уверены что хотите выбросить предмет?')) use_item('drop');"><P>&nbsp;<P>
 <select size="1" name="pokes" style='display:none'><P>
  <input name="but1" style='display:none' type="button" value="Использовать" onclick="use_item('use');">
  <input name="but2" style='display:none' type="button" value="Одеть" onclick="use_item('dress');">

  <input name="itID" type="hidden" value="">
  <input name="add" id="add" type="hidden" value="">
</form>

</TD></TR><TR><TD>

</TD></TR></TABLE>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

так и не понял что нужно автору вывести но если правильно уловил суть то ......

```
$inv[$i]['нужные значения'] //пример
//насколько я понял тебе нужна эта строка
i[$i] = new Array('".$inv[$i]['id']."',
  '".$inv[$i]['id_img']."',
  '".$inv[$i]['kolovo']."',
  0,
  '".$inv[$i]['title']."',
  0,
  '".$inv[$i]['about']."',
  0,
  1
);
```

будет выводить все что найдет по данному юзеру в цикле пака значения $i не сравняются с заданным циклом

Comment: археолог что-ли?

Comment: да я чет не посмотрел на дату сразу .... , взял репутацию испортил (((

Comment: отредактируй пост

Comment: @ikerya, ответ отредактирован.

Comment: готово.........

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print $line['id'];
    print $line['id_img'];
    print $line['kolovo']
    //И т.д. и т.п.
}
```

Идея понятна? Учите матчасть как бы...

Comment: ша так попробую

Comment: код покажи целиком

Comment: окай, секундочку

Comment: удали этот участок, который начинается с for, вообще... я написал как переделать его уже

Comment: нет, так не пойдет =(